# Add rewrite rules for pagination

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, url-rewriting, endpoint

I need to add rewrite rules for pagination on my endpoint with a query using `wl_paged` variable.

I want to achieve this: https://example.com/wishlist/?wl_paged=2

So I tried using [add_rewrite_rule](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/), but it doesn't work the link is still https://example.com/wishlist.

```
function add_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'wishlist', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES ); 
    add_rewrite_rule( 'wl_paged/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?$', 'index.php?wl_paged=$matches[1]', 'top');
    
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_endpoint' );

add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'wl_paged';
    return $query_vars;
});
```

Can anybody help me do it?

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? Are you getting an error, the wrong page, a 404 error? We can't help you fix the problem if we don't know what the problem is!

Comment: The link is still https://example.com/wishlist/